# A way to match the id of the id of the selected input field in SQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql

Say if I were to select a input with it's own photo and I want to add text to that specific photo to its input. How would I accomplish that? Here is my attempt of doing that:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];     
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pictures");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE username = '$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $id = $row['id'];
        $send = $_POST['send'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pictures");
        $sql = "UPDATE images SET send='$send' WHERE username='$username' AND id='$id'";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        header("Location: index");
    } else {
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="send_message" method="post">
<input name="send" placeholder="Send message" />
<button name="submit"></button>
</form>
```

The problem I'm having is when I do add text, it doesn't go to the picture I selected but instead to the first one that matches the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send an id of the picture you want to change `send` value for.
You can cast it to int and use prepared statements, and select database row with that id along with user (don't select just by id, so it won't be possible to change value for picture that user sending a form is not owner of)

so your form should look something like:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?PHP echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
    <input type="text" name="send" placeholder="Send message"/>
    <button name="submit"></button>
</form>
```

So you need to create hidden field with id of phone you want to set new `send` value. I assumed that you have a row from database which id would be inserted as value of the hidden id field. But you can use `$_GET['id']` or `$_POST['id']` if you create link/button to redirect user to page where one will edit a photo.

You could also set value of the hidden id field with javascript by clicking on a photo.

Comment: I see, do I have to do anything to my query up there? I could use `$_POST['id']` but I need to experiment if it properly inserts into the correct picture.

Comment: @HannahParks Your update query already has id so it will update only picture with the id, and if id is primary key then there will be one picture with this id max, it may be one or none since picture with id may not exist but there won't be many pictures with same id. What you can do is to prepare your queries to avoid sql injections. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php It will send query as query and data as data, so data won't be interpreted as query by the server.